# Firebase database error: Constructor Set requires 'new'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using firebase realtime database in plain js
my code:

```
Set(ref(database, 'users/' + user.uid),{
 username: username,
})
```

my error:
Constructor Set requires 'new'

i just tried my code that was written using a tutorial on yt

Comment: We need more context (or, at least, I do). What is `Set` ? Based on the error message, it seems to be a class, if that is the case, you need to use `new Set(..)`.

Comment: If you're trying to do [something like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write) maybe you've imported the wrong thing (`Set` instead of `set`)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.